# Does Glimpse work on actions that return JsonResult?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, glimpse

I've got an app where most of the heavy lifting is in actions that each return a JsonResult. They're called by jQuery from a simple view.

The requests show up in the Ajax tab in Glimpse, but as each request completes it gets scored through and greyed out. I'd like to inspect each of those ajax requests and see the Glimpse information for them -- the MVC routing, execution, binding, trace output, etc.  Is that possible?

(I'm using Glimpse v0.81)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default Glimpse data is only generated for certain content types. (text/html)

In the  section of your web.config you can add application/json (or whatever content type you are returning) and Glimpse will begin to provide all of the server metadata you are looking for.

Comment: What section of the web config please?

Answer (score 1):

Normally Glimpse supports AJAX requests but [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) and Developer tools in Google Chrome seems a better suited tools for inspecting them.

Comment: @jgauffin, yes, it's good. I've updated my answer to include your suggestion.

Comment: It's a good suggestion (and Fiddler is great for this stuff too), but it's the MVC specific stuff that I'm interested in getting from Glimpse -- the route debugging, execution info, Trace output, etc.